# Use AOP in a Spring Boot app to log methods calls and their parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, aop, spring-aop

Rather than manually writing code such as

```
public void someMethod(Object someArg, Object otherArg) {
    logger.trace("someMethod invoked with arguments {}, {}", someArg, otherArg);    

    // method body
}
```

I would like to generate such statements automatically using AOP. The app in question is a Spring Boot 2.3.3 app.

I don't think it's possible to generate logging statements for *all* method calls using AOP, only for methods calls on Spring beans. This would be good enough for my current purposes.

Could someone explain the specific steps for how I add an aspect to a Spring Boot app that will generate a log statement such as the above for all method calls on Spring beans? If only public method calls can be intercepted by the aspect, that would be good enough.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the example in the Spring AOP documentation

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks research effort (logging is the classic example for AOP and there are dozens or hundreds of tutorials/examples out there) and it also asks volunteers to do the whole job without showing what was tried so far.

Comment: @kriegaex if it's such an easy question to answer, why not post an answer instead?

Comment: I just explained why. Please re-read my comment.

Comment: @kriegaex there's nothing in the stackoverflow rules that says easy questions are not allowed or that a significant research effort must be demonstrated. AFAIK, any on-topic question that is sufficiently narrow in scope, and hasn't already been asked, is valid

Comment: It is not about easy or difficult, of course easy questions are OK. The questions here should be like: ***"I tried X and had problem Y. Here is my code reproducing the problem."*** They should not be like: _"I want to do X (+ 1 line of pseudo code), but with technology Y. Please redundantly present the full solution to me, even though there are hundreds of solutions I could find by googling 10 seconds, there are dozens of duplicates here on StackOverflow already and the exact same use case is also handled in the manual of the very tool I want to use."_ With all due respect, that is just weak.

Comment: @kriegaex again, you're composing your own set of rules about what type of questions are allowed, which are inconsistent with the _actual_ rules. For example, you're implying that if an answer can be found "by googling 10 seconds" or reading the manual then the question is not allowed. Neither of these are StackOverflow rules, they're your rules. Please familiarize yourself with the actual StackOverflow rules and follow those instead.

Comment: Sorry you do not like my criticism, which I am not backing off of. I mean what I said. If you feel offended though, I apologise. If you disagree, feel free to do so. Actually I am trying to guide you to write better questions which would also lead to a much higher probability of getting good and helpful answers. Good luck.

Comment: This guy even did not share link to which documentation, if there is such example in documentation that specifically answers this.

Answer (score 8):

It's true that you can only advice public methods of Spring beans if you use the proxy-based Spring AOP framework (personally, I find that this is usually good enough). With native AspectJ weaving you could advice any method.

First, create an aspect class annotated with `@Aspect`, and either with `@component` for component scanning or declared as a `@Bean` in your configuration.

Then, in the class, you need a pointcut that defines which methods are adviced, and an advice to tell what to do (e.g., do some logging in your case).

A pointcut to advice all public methods or Spring Beans would look like this:

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
public void publicMethod() {}
```

Or if you just want to log service methods, you could use:

```
@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Service *)")
public void withinService() {}
```

An advice can run before (`@Before`), after (`@After`) or both (`@Around`) your methods. For logging, I would use an `@Around` advice. Note that you can also combine pointcuts with logical operators:

```
@Around("publicMethod() && withinService()")
public Object profileServiceMethods(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    // do some logging before method execution
    Object retVal = joinPoint.proceed();
    // and some logging after method execution
    return retVal;
}
```

You can also look at my ready-to-use [AOProfiling](https://github.com/rechnerherz/aoprofiling-spring-boot-starter) Spring Boot starter for a full example.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class LoggingAspectConfig {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository *)"
            + " || within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Service *)"
            + " || within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *)")
    public void springBeanPointcut() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Pointcut("within(com.softilys.soyouz.repository..*)"
            + " || within(com.softilys.soyouz.service.helpers.impl..*)"
            + " || within(com.softilys.soyouz.rest.web..*)")
    public void applicationPackagePointcut() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "applicationPackagePointcut() && springBeanPointcut()", throwing = "e")
    public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e) {
        logger.error("Exception in {}.{}() with cause = {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), e.getCause() != null ? e.getMessage() : "NULL");
    }

    @Around("applicationPackagePointcut() && springBeanPointcut()")
    public Object invoke(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        final String joinPoints = Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs());
        if (joinPoints != null) {
            logger.info("Enter: {}.{}() with argument[s] = {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                    joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), joinPoints);
        }
        final Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
        logger.info("Exit: {}.{}() with result = {}", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), result);
        return result;
    }

}
```